# Accessing BasicHttpBinding endpoint fails with System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: 'Access is denied.'

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wcf-endpoint, wcf-configuration

I have a WCF service exposing basic HTTP binding and HTTPS binding (with federation).
The client app can access the service with HTTPS, but the basic HTTP endpoint method access started giving "Access denied"(System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: 'Access is denied.')

When enabled HTTPS with SSL- The HTTPS endpoint methods are accessible but basic HTTP binding giving Access denied.

Without HTTPS & SSL enablement, BasicHttp binding was working perfectly fine.

Tried with by adding service authorization principal permission mode as "None" but no benefit.

My binding config is,

```
<ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ws2007FederationHttpBinding1">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message establishSecurityContext="false" issuedKeyType="BearerKey"/>               
        </security>
    </binding>
</ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
```

Any Support is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your complete configuration code?

Comment: The requirement is same as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294665/different-service-behaviors-per-endpoint   we have our extension to support httpsbinding with federation support which is applied at the service behaviour. Since the service is same , both httpGet and httpsGet enabled at the servicebehaviour level. Issue is httpBinding also expecting same security setting since servicebehaviour is same and hence getting access denied. Http should work without any security demand.What is the option? No plan to have seperate service deployment for http and https endpoints.

Comment: Refer to this, you can achieve your function;https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/multiple-endpoints?redirectedfrom=MSDN